# Add gridview column in code behind

Tags: asp.net

I am working on gridview in C# and I need to add a column dynamically.
I need to achieve the following mark up in the code behind,

```
   <headertemplate>                          
    <a href="javascript:var popup = window.open('Pop.aspx? param=myParameter','Pop','width=200,height=200');">
     <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="ColumnName" 
      ToolTip="Click here for more information"></asp:Label>
       </a>
   </headertemplate>
<Itemtemplate>
....
```

The column has underline where user can click to open a popup.

Thanks.

Comment: have you ever thought about ditching the prefab asp.net controls and dynamically building your own table?

Comment: Tony what did you try so far to get what you want and what did you get?

Comment: So far, I create a template class to represent a dynamic template column (example from msdn) and I can add a column but I am not sure to make the header clickable (for popup).